# My printer adds a blue background

Tags: printing, hp, ghostscript

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04LTS. I have an HP Photosmart C7280 color printer. The printer is attached over the local network. This has worked nicely for me for a long time.

But today, suddenly, everything I print gets a solid blue background. I can still read the text, but the entire page background is blue. Other computers can print to the same printer without problems; the blue background is only added on one computer.

I've tried restarting both the computer and the printer. I've removed the printer from my Linux configuration and added it again. The result is always the same. Even the print test page feature of the printer installation program adds a blue background.

What can I do?

**EDIT**

The problem seems to be caused by an update to ghostscript. My ghostscript 9.26 was updated today. I tried another Linux system with an older version of ghostscript 9.26, and it worked nicely. I then updated ghostscript on that system, and then I got a blue background.

How do I force the system back to the older (working) version of ghostscript?

**EDIT2**

This is definitely a bug. It has been reported by others in the Ubuntu bug tracker: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ghostscript/+bug/1817308

Comment: Did you try printing with a different operating system or a live usb?

Comment: It works from a Linux Mint computer and a Windows computer.

Comment: [How to report bugs?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: You might get deb files for older version ghostscript in launchpad. Uninstall current version. Use the one that works. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ghostscript

Comment: FYI. bug was patched today(20190223). http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/g/ghostscript/ghostscript_9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.18.04.6/changelog Update your ghostscript package

Answer (score 2):

Installing an older version of ghostscript restores the ability to print properly.

I run this command:

```
sudo apt install ghostscript=9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2 \
libgs9=9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2 \
libgs9-common=9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2
```

and now my Ubuntu 16.04 prints properly.

In order to stop the update happening again, I run this command:

```
sudo apt-mark hold ghostscript=9.18~dfsg-0-0ubuntu2
```

Reference: [Bug #1817308 “GhostScript Update causes Blue Background”](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ghostscript/+bug/1817308)

Comment: I don't know how but ghostscript updated itself again to 9.26 and still does not  work,  this time giving an error message: "filter failed". So I went  back to 9.18 and it works again.

Comment: where do I do that?

Comment: ok, so now I'll go to Launch pad and try to report a bug there.   Though I can't see why this is not an appropriate forum - 16.04 LTS would not seem to be a development version, but then I'm rather new to this and am only trying to help other people who may also be banging their head against a brick wall trying to get their  printer to do a simple print.

Comment: Just updated and the problem persists: "filter failed"

Comment: As of 6/3/19 the update finally works.