# Blue background when printing

Tags: 18.04

I am getting blue backgrounds when I print. I have read the reports that the problem is caused by a ghostscript upgrade. I never heard of ghostscript and don't know if I have it. Needless to say that this newby is confused!

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120379/my-printer-adds-a-blue-background

Comment: And https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413260

Answer (score 2):

You correctly linked to an issue with an update of ghostscript, which causes the problem. [The bug is reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ghostscript/+bug/1817308).

To **work around** the issue, try **downgrading to the previous version** as suggested in the bug report. Although you are a beginner, easiest way is to open the terminal, copy the following command and paste it in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install ghostscript=9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1 libgs9=9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1 libgs9-common=9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu1
```

This will install the slightly older ghostscript version, replacing the current erroneous one.

Now, any attempt to update the system would also update the package again. To prevent that from happening, you can temporary **"lock" the current version**. You can do this with synaptic package manager, but it might be easier with a command:

```
sudo apt-mark hold ghostscript libgs9 libgs9-common
```

This command locks the currently installed version, i.e., the good one you installed with previous command, preventing it from being updated.

When the bug is solved, you may again want to "subscribe" to the updates. Unlock the current version with the command

```
sudo apt-mark unhold ghostscript libgs9 libgs9-common
```

From then on, the packages will again be updated as updates become available in the Ubuntu software sources.

The quality control of the Ubuntu software sources is good. This does not prohibit an erroneous update from slipping through now and then.

Comment: The bug is fixed now. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ghostscript/+bug/1817308 a new version of ghostscript is available for upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

This bug was fixed in the package ghostscript - 9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.14.04.6

i updated it today using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install ghostscript
```

and do a restart to make sure everything is updated.
thanks